# Does not appear power pivot add-in in Excel 2013

Tags: excel-2013, powerpivot

I have Excel 2013 inside the Office 2013 Home & business suite and when I try to enable Power Pivot by Options>add-in>COM components the Power Pivot does not appear.

Any Idea please?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power Pivot add-in is only available in Microsoft Office Professional Plus and Office 365 Professional Plus editions.

Check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/417a711e-9747-437f-aa63-03657aacd47c/power-view-in-excel-2013-home-and-business-edition?forum=sqlreportingservices).